# Can't connect to mongodb using C++

Tags: c++, mongodb

OS ubuntu 13.10 64bit

mongodb installed with aptitude, version 2.4.6 which according to the documentation should not be a problem to connect to.

I have a mongodb instance running (the question right now is for localhost). I've found the sample code in [mongodb site](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/download-and-compile-cpp-driver/) and tried to compile it with the client version that I have.
That wasn't working, so I've downloaded the git version and compiled the library myself. 
I got no error now, however, when trying to connect, I'm getting the "can't connect" exception.
here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
    cout<<"Mongo client test.\r\n";
    mongo::DBClientConnection conn;
    try {
        conn.connect("localhost");
    }
    catch(const mongo::DBException &e ) {
        cout <<"error connecting to localhost:"<<endl;
        std::cout << e.what()<<".\r\n";
        return -1;
    }
    cout<<"connected!";
    //cin;
    return 0;
}
```

this is the output:

```
Mongo client test.

error connecting to localhost:

can't connect .
```

since it does compile and run, I see no error with the process, but there might be one with the connection itself, or I might be forgetting something.

The instance is up and running, JS clients and robomongo connects to it without an issue.
Any idea will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that one must use the current library.
Although I've installed mongo-dev(aptitude), it wasn't working.
When I used the downloaded mongo folder (after fixing some errors) it is working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but comments just don't work for this detail:

First, follow the instructions on [Installing for Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) from the MongoDB site. Haven't checked but the version number seems low for your current release.

Also include the port number for completeness in your connect, making sure that your other clients on the "localhost" are also using this port.

```
conn.connect("localhost:27017");
```

Both go some way to diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @donald Well there is definitely something wrong with your connect. You are on the same host as where `mongod` is running aren't you?

Comment: yes. I've just solved it by using the lib headers instead of mongo's